# JTable in a JScrollPane doesn't automatically repaint when scrolling

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jscrollpane, concurrency

I have a `JScrollPane` that holds a `JTable`. The table is dynamically populated from a database query. That all works fine and the table is getting populated, but its wider than the visible window.

I can see the left part of the table and I need to scroll right to see the right end of it. When I do that, the part of the table that was hidden (right end) is blurred. Then I stop scrolling and wait few seconds and then it is repainted and looks fine. I scroll back left and everything is OK - no blur.

- I guess I'm missing some force repaint - but shouldn't `JScrollPane` handle it automatically ?
- How do I get rid of this effect ?

Here is how I construct it (I wont paste all the code since it basically work):

```
    jScrollPane1.setAutoscrolls(true);
    jScrollPane1.getViewport().setLayout(borderLayout2);        
    jScrollPane1.getViewport().add(table, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    this.add(jScrollPane1, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: my two cents that this issue hasn't something with JTable and JScrollPane but with `The table is dynamically populated from a database query`

Answer (score 3):

Never seen such an artifact, might be due to the fact that you are adding the table in a completely wrong manner. Replace the first three lines of your snippet with:

```
jScrollPane1.setViewportView(table);
```

Comment: @mKorbel and probably off the EDT :-)

Comment: +1, 1) for JTable 2) I tried yours newest child and without any bugs for standard Swing methods + older Substance, 3) please is there some road_plan or current version is all that I need/wanted :-)

Comment: @mKorbel hmm .. not quite sure what you mean, so just throwing out a random comment: SwingX 1.6.3 has rollout status, the announcement should come one of these days :-)